# Function in HTML to grab the object (SVG) where I click?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm searching for some function to grab the information about the object who is clicked, for example, the page have 2 rects in one page, the user click on one, I want to know in what object the user clicked.

Example:

```
<rect onclick='changerect(evt)' x="1" y="1" height="30" width="50" style="fill:gray;
stroke-width:0.5; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
<rect onclick='changerect(evt)' x="1" y="31" height="100" width="10" style="fill:gray;
stroke-width:0.5; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />

<script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    function changerect(evt) {
        var svgobj=evt.target;
        svgobj.style.opacity= 0.3;
    }
]]>
</script>
```

Calling the fuction the object will change the opacity, there any way to I know what object was the one where the user clicked?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense, svgobj is the one the user clicked on!

Comment: Yeah, but I have 2 rects on my page, in what the user clicked?
I want know that.

The rects dont have any name, is not like C, have some kind of function to give a name to the rects?

Exemple:
<rect name='rect1'...

And for script:
function changerect(evt, name)...


Thank you.

Comment: function changerect(svobj)

Comment: Thank you for the help.
The user uʍopǝpısdn answer me with one functional code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `rect`s an `id` then you can access this from your existing `svgobj` variable like so:

`svgobj.id`

Example:

```html
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    function changerect(evt) {
        var svgobj=evt.target;
        svgobj.style.opacity= 0.3;
        alert(svgobj.id);
    }

</script>

<svg>
<rect id="rect1" onclick='changerect(evt)' x="1" y="1" height="30" width="50" style="fill:gray;
stroke-width:0.5; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
<rect id="rect2" onclick='changerect(evt)' x="1" y="31" height="100" width="10" style="fill:gray;
stroke-width:0.5; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```